# Add css template in other than index.html(masterpage) in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I attached a css template to the masterpage in my asp.net website. Now I need to create another blank page and link it to the masterpage(index.html)i.e Default.aspx. In the newly created web form how to attach the same css template. please help???????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you link same master page to another blank page say - Default.aspx then it will automatically use css apply in master page

read master page related tutorial here

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages